# jQuery DataTables: Filter per column

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a DataTables table, which is getting it's data trough an AJAX source. I've got the table up and running, even searching works.

Now I've got a request to implement search fields for every column. There seems to be a DataTables Plugin for column filtering, which I tried to use.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>testpage</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.company.com/content/dam/workflows/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#overview").dataTable({
            aoColumnDefs:[{
                aTargets: [0]
            }],
            bAutoWidth: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            iDisplayLength: 10,
            sAjaxSource: "http://server/api.jsp?someparameters"
        }).columnFilter();
    })
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<table id="overview">
<tr>
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Betrieb</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Anlagenummer</th>
        <th>Bezeichnung</th>
    </thead>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I just attached the columnFilter() method. It doesn't even throw an error in the console, but the table looks just like before (no additional input boxes to search the columns).

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible due to the source beeing AJAX?

Comment: Where is `<tfoot>` tag?

Comment: Oh my... Can't believe I didn't see that, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to define a footer section in your html table. Have a look at [this example](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html)

The table should look like

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, that was exactly what was causing the problem!

Comment: I couldn't get this working with DataTables 1.10.2. Should it work with 1.10.+? The plugin's demo site only uses Datatables 1.8 and 1.9 back from 2011-2012. I have a bad feeling it's not up to date :(